# Is it possible to view Oracle user table privileges without having DBA privilege?

Tags: oracle, roles, privileges

Is it possible to view the roles of the user without having DBA Privilege? If so, how?

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE = 'USER_NAME';
```

The above query needs the "SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE" role.

I need to get the result of the above query without (DBA and SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE) Privileges.

Comment: +1 for the best/worst question title

Comment: And I don't know why there's a downvote. It just needed 30 seconds of cleaning to make into a good, solid question.

Comment: 30 seconds the questioner might have put in before asking the question (not that i downvoted)

Comment: Based on the question content, it seems to me like a better title would be "Is it possible to view Oracle user table privileges without having DBA privilege?". Roles in Oracle are actually something different than the question implies. Table privileges can be granted via roles.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps `ALL_TAB_PRIVS` will provide what you want. Apparently, it contains:

> Grants on objects for which the user is the grantor, grantee, owner, or an enabled role or PUBLIC is the grantee

Comment: Adam Paynter, Thanks for ur answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

See me what GRANTs and Privileges I have:

```
SELECT * FROM user_tab_privs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the DBA create a new role and grant the new role select on the table. The DBA could then grant you the new role which will allow you to see the table without DBA or select catalog role.

Answer (score 0):

DBA_TAB_PRIVS
DBA_SYS_PRIVS
DBA_ROLE_PRIVS

Here are the main tables you can check for roles and privs