# Difference between query of privileges in tables

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges

Reading [this answe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166064/is-it-possible-to-view-oracle-user-table-privileges-without-having-dba-privilege)r I found a query to find the privileges of a table:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_PRIVS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
```

But a friend give me to me this query:

```
select a.USERNAME,a.GRANTED_ROLE,b.ROLE,b.owner,b.TABLE_NAME,b.privilege
from user_role_privs a,role_tab_privs b
where b.ROLE=a.GRANTED_ROLE and b.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';
```

There is some substantial difference between each query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are quite different, yes.

In Oracle, privileges on a table can be granted either directly to a user (in which case they would appear in `ALL_TAB_PRIVS`) or privileges can be granted to a role (visible in `ROLE_TAB_PRIVS`) and that role can be granted to a user (visible in `USER_ROLE_PRIVS`).  The first query will show you the users that have direct grants on a table.  The second query will show you the users that have been granted a role that has been granted access to the table (note that in both cases you really ought to specify an `OWNER` in addition to the table name).  Neither will show you information about grants that have been made through multiple nested levels of roles (i.e. User A has been granted Role 1, Role 1 has been granted Role 2, Role 2 has been granted access to a table).  Grants made via roles can also get a bit tricky because there are default and non-default roles and password protected roles and roles can be enabled and disabled in a session.

In general, I'd suggest taking a look at the [scripts available on Pete Finnigan's site](http://www.petefinnigan.com/tools.htm) if you want to have something that covers all the possible cases.  In this case, you probably want to use his [who_can_access script](http://www.petefinnigan.com/who_can_access.sql) to determine what users can access a particular table.

Comment: I don't understand the part in where you specified that the query needs the owner of the table. I made both queries and the only I wrote in the WHERE clause was the table name and nothing more.

Comment: @Galled - `ALL_TAB_PRIVS` has a `TABLE_SCHEMA` column and `ROLE_TAB_PRIVS` has an `OWNER` column.  Your queries almost certainly want to specify the owner/ schema of the table.  Otherwise, if a table with the same name is created in a different schema, the results of your query will suddenly change in a potentially subtle fashion.