# How to grant privileges to user to access dba_objects of granted tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g, schema, privileges

I am creating a sample application that generate a schema sql file for the given schema.
I have a system previleges user say SYSTEM. I have another user as tester1 and I gave all privileges to tester1.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO SCOTT;
OR
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on table_name TO SCOTT;
```

Now I am login with tester1 and want to access SYSTEM schema.
Using following query

```
select object_type from dba_objects where owner = 'SYSTEM' and object_name = 'table_name'
```

it gives an error :- `table or views does not exists.`

But when I run select * from "SYSTEM".table_name; I got all records.

What query will give full privileges to tester1 ?

Comment: Access to the DBA tables is privileged. You may grant the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE to the user if you need read access to the DBA_% views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to view Oracle user table privileges without having DBA privilege?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166064/is-it-possible-to-view-oracle-user-table-privileges-without-having-dba-privilege)